# What is the Korean word for Orach (an edible leafy green similair to Spinach)?

Tags: food

### What is the Korean word for [**Orach**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atriplex_hortensis) (an edible leafy green similar to Spinach also known as *Atriplex Hortensis*)?

### "Orach"에 대한 한국어는 무엇입니까?

### 시금치와 비슷한 식용 잎이 많은 녹색입니다.

[image: a picture or orach]

Answer (score 0):

I found the following on Google:
오라치, 적색오크라, or 갯능쟁이, none of which seem to be any more popular than the others. This type of herb is not so popular in Korea I guess. So, there is no single dominant or most popular term for this herb.